# Prove that a multivariable function has an absolute minimum yet no absolute maximum on a open set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Define $f(x,y)=xy+\frac{3}{x}+\frac{4}{y}$ on the set $\{(x,y):x,y>0\}$. How could it be proven that $f$ has an absolute minimum but no absolute maximum on this set.

One idea which I had was to use a theorem which states roughly:
"Let $f$ be a continuous function on an unbounded closed set $S \subset \mathbb R^n.$ If $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$, then $f$ has an absolute minimum but no absolute maximum on S." The function seems to be continuous on this set. Regardless it seems to be inapplicable to the above case since the set $\{(x,y):x,y>0\}$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

To show there is no absolute maximum, you can think for any $M\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a pair $(x_1,y_1)\in A:=\{(x,y):x,y>0\}$ such that $|f(x_1,y_1)|>M$. But in this case, you do not need both $x,y$ to be free. For example, $f(1,y)=4+y+\dfrac{4}{y}$ already has no absolute maximum (try! Use single variable to show no absolute maximum).

To show there is an absolute minimum, an intuitive guess is that it should be a local minimum also as it has no 'boundary' in $A$. Then apply standard multivariable optimization tricks, you should solve $$\textbf{x}=(\hat{x},\hat{y})=\left(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9}{4}},\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{16}{3}}\right)\tag{*}$$
which is also the unique critical point in $A$. To show this is local minimum, use Hessian or definition to prove is ok. Then since $f$ is continuous over $A$, $f$ must also attain absolute minimum at that point in this region.

**Edit 2:** Thanks for clarifying again. Let's use another approach. Note as $(x_1,y_1)\to(x,y)\in\partial A$, $f(x,y)\to+\infty$. We use the extended $\mathbb{R}$ system so that $f$ can be defined on $\bar{A}=\{(x,y):x,y\ge0\}$. Then write $c=f(\textbf{x})$. Choose $M>0$ such that $f(x,y)>c$ whenever $|x-\hat{x}|>M$ or $|y-\hat{y}|>M$. We set $$S=\{(x,y)\in\tilde{A}:|x-\hat{x}|,|y-\hat{y}|\le M\}$$ This is a compact set (Closeness come from $\tilde{A}$ is closed). So global extrema of $f$ under this restriction exists as $f$ is continuous over there. Let the global minimum be attained at $(a,b)$. Now, $f(\textbf{x})\ge f(a,b)$ as \textbf{x}$\in S$. For $(h,k)\notin S$, either $|h-\hat{x}|$ or $|k-\hat{y}|>M$, so $$f(h,k)>c\ge f(a,b)$$ In another words, this $(a,b)$ is also the global minimum in $\tilde{A}$. But this must not be a boundary point as every point on the boundary is $+\infty$, so $(a,b)\in A$. This means $f$ has global minimum in $A$.

Comment: Justify your last sentence.

Comment: Now your last claim is false. There are functions of $n\ge 2$ variables with a single critical point, a local minimum, and no absolute minimum whatsoever.

Comment: I understand how the non existence of absolute maximum was proved. Still unsure how to go about proving that the local minimum is the absolute minimum on the set.

Comment: More likely, using $AM\ge GM$ may even more convenient as it provides the lower bound of $f$, and it is achievable by solving $xy=\dfrac{3}{x}=\dfrac{4}{y}$. 

Apart from that, you can also show the global minimum exist as shown in **Edit 2**, the idea is $f\to+\infty$ at the boundary of $A$, so the minimum (if exist), cannot occur on the boundary part. If we assign $+\infty$ instead of calling it undefined to $f$ at that place, then we can make $A$ into a closed set (including its boundaries), so to apply extreme value theorem.

Comment: You do not need to mess with taking the closure of $A$. As you did, just choose a compact set $S$ containing $(\hat x,\hat y)$ so that outside that compact set you can estimate that $f>c$. (You did not really do this. You asserted the existence of $M$ but did not prove it. Usually, you will want a shape different from a rectangle to do this estimate more easily.) Then the Maximum Value Theorem guarantees an absolute minimum on $S$, and the estimate outside of $S$ shows that it is an absolute minimum on all of $A$.